# Android Studio - can't start work with project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-support-library

I have one error when I start my project in Android Studio.
[image]

When I try `Install Repository and sync project` I got this:

[image]

I have normal internet connection.

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: Did you compile `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87'` ? .Then Clean-Rebuild-Sync Your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At First **`Update Your Android SDK Tools (Support Repository )`**

Then add this in your **build.gradle** section

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:6.5.87'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux den run android studio in administrator mode and then download it. by command

```
cd path of studio/bin
sudo ./studio.sh
```

or you can use below version which is installed in your studio